# Does Mac restart work reliably with restoring open applications/dev-tools and restoring states in every case?

Tags: macos, restore, restart

I'm new to Mac. So far when restarting everything worked reliably as it did before and was more or less in the same state.

Can I as a dev lean on not losing any state information when restarting? Can every application be restored completely and when does data loss occur? Are there any known bugs? Can I leave my debugger at a point in my application, restart/sleep and expect to be in the same state with my debugger?

Before getting too comfortable with the feature I want to know how much I can rely on it to restore everything to the previous state, otherwise I will be more cautious with restarts, so I think this info is helpful for any dev using Mac OS X as a platfom to develop.

Comment: You mention two things, restarting and sleeping. For sleeping, I'd expect things to basically remain in the same state. For restarting, it's basically going to open your apps back up. I would not expect things like in progress debugging to be maintained as the processes will be stopped and restarted as part of the restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications to not get restore state functionality magically but they support APIs that help doing it. Some applications do it well, others less well and others not at all.

In practice, for the applications that support it, it works quite reliably, provided the logout went cleanly and you've not out of diskspace or something similar fatal.